# Json success IF result is Acting unlike it does on LocalHost when ON HOST

Tags: php, json

This code seems to Run the IF statement regardless of what data is returned

On LOCALHOST it will work fine. However on HOST it will not, i will get different results...

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url:"bandatabasecheck.php",
                 type: "POST",
                  dataType: 'text',
                  cache: false,
                    data:{
                        youripcheck:yourip,
                        },
                        async: true,
                            success: function(returned){
                              let data = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(returned)));
                              if (data='BANNED') {
                                  //window.location.assign('banned.php');
                                   console.log('Your' +returned);
                                   data=null; returned=null;
                                  }
                                  else {console.log('Not Yet'+data);}
                                  
                              },
                                 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {console.log('THERES AN ERROR', textStatus, errorThrown);}  
       });
});
```

Currently it will console log 'your'+data regardless of the data, when it should only be doing so if data = 'BANNED'

I have tried using == but then it skips the IF and run the ELSE resulting in 'Not Yet'+BANNED

The Json return is from a simple PHP echo in bandatabasecheck.php
And that is fine it works as it should returning BANNED or Nothing , but then the Json sucess IF function failed to run correctly.

```
if ($countcheckban > 1){echo 'BANNED'; $countcheckban = null; }else{echo 'Nothing';}
```

FOLLOWING 6 IMAGES ARE FROM LOCALHOST

IF data = (data Being BANNED)

[image]

IF data = (data Being NOT BANNED)

[image]

---

IF data == (data Being BANNED)

[image]

IF data == (data Being NOT BANNED)

[image]

---

IF data === (data Being BANNED)

[image]

IF data === (data Being NOT BANNED)

[image]

BUT as soon as I run the same on HOST

I get the following results, and yes i clear cache.

IF data === (data Being BANNED)

[image]

IF data === (data Being NOT BANNED)

[image]

---

IF data == (data Being BANNED)

[image]

IF data == (data Being NOT BANNED)

[image]

---

IF data = (data Being BANNED)

[image]

IF data = (data Being NOT BANNED)

[image]

Something is very wrong on my Hosting for it to be throwing these results.

Does anybody Have any Idea what could be causing this.

Yes the code & database are the same on LOCAL and HOST

Yes I clear Cache and refresh database and HOST code before I reload the page.

So why would it be producing these results.

Very strange. I'm very frustrated with it indeed.

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What's the point of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))`? It is a no-op.

Comment: i was just making sure it was returning the word 'BANNED' Correctly, im very new to all this.

Comment: [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) takes a data structure and encodes it as [JSON](https://json.org). [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) takes a JSON and parse it into a data structure equivalent to the data structure used to generate the JSON. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` produces a deep clone of `data`, nothing more. It is completely useless here.

Comment: If the server returns the JSON correctly (i.e. if it puts the header `Content-Type: application/json` in the response) then `$.ajax()` parses the JSON and calls your callback with a data structure, not with the JSON received in the response body. There is nothing to parse, it is already parsed.

Comment: ok, i will rmove the stringify. i added it to see if the BANNED being received from the PHP Echo was causing an issue.

Comment: The odds are that your PHP has leading and/or trailing white space so the string isn't matching. Use JSON instead of plain text for your data format.

Comment: so json back to the json. How i go about that from PHP

Comment: Remove all these useless screenshots from the question.

Comment: They are very usefull indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the line:

```js
if (data='BANNED')
```

`=` is the [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment). The expression on the right-hand side is evaluated (it is the string `'BANNED'` here) and its value is assigned to the variable on the left-hand side (`data` here).
The value of the assignment expression is the value of its right-hand side expression (`'BANNED'`).

In a boolean context, the value `'BANNED'` is evaluated as `true`, therefore the `if` branch is always executed.

Use the [strict equality operator (`===`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality).

```js
if (data === 'BANNED') ...
```

Comment: yes thats it, thats what i was thinking,i have also tried ===. i will try it again and post the result.

Comment: Something amiss, been meddling with this for 24 hours. been getting incorrect results. being sent to BAN page when shouldn't of been ect. i Think it had something to do with  the Cache. and the Operator being = or == - i wasn't using === although i did try it.

Comment: Both `==` and `===` should work, given that the data that you receive from the remote server is what you think it is. Use `console.log(returned)` to find out how it looks like. Or, better, use Postman or another similar tool to issue a request to the remote PHP server and see what it returns.